# If a single contact in a parallel circuit shorts out, can it ark?

Tags: voltage, current, switches, dc, arc

I am considering stress test scenarios for solderless battery packs, to know how much destructive impact they can handle before internal arcing can happen on individual batteries.

If you have 200 volts at 100 Amperes coming from a 5p50s battery box, and you interrupt 1-2 batteries physically for 10ms, is it possible for there to be an arc, considering that the current can still pass through the neighbouring batteries?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Arc where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *will* be an arc, due to inductance in the wiring and the battery itself.

*Any* time you interrupt the flow of current through a circuit which has inductance, a voltage is produced equal to the rate of current change multiplied by the inductance (this is actually the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) of inductance). If the current changes quickly then a high voltage will be produced.

When a switch carrying current opens it tries to instantaneously drop the current to zero. But this can't happen because an infinite voltage would be produced. So the voltage rises until it forms an arc across the contacts, which then allows the current to drop more gradually. This continues until the energy stored by the inductance is dissipated in the arc.

In your case, even though the other batteries 'take up the slack' and supply full current to the load, there is still an (attempted) instantaneous drop from 20A to 0A in the circuit of the battery that became disconnected. Since all wires have inductance, some arcing *will* occur. However if the wiring between batteries is very short and fat then the inductance (and arcing) will be minimized.

A little bit of arcing isn't necessarily bad. It actually helps to keep contact resistance down by punching through the oxide layer that forms on the surface of the metal. This is important because at high current, even a small resistance can make a big difference to how evenly the individual batteries discharge.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is about arcing in a switch, as the OP mentions "internal arcing [...] on individual batteries".

Comment: I use the word 'switch' generically. Switch, plug and socket, 'solderless battery pack' are all the same electrically - two metal contacts are pushed together to make a connection and separated to break it.

Comment: Thank you very much for an enlightening and fascinating answer. it's a starting point to find a lot of reading material.